# Customers using Cyrillic or Russian alphabet

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, invoice, language, internationalization, utf-8

I am working on a UK-based site - but we have customers all over the world, including Russia. However, when customers enter their address using the non-latin Russian / Cyrillic alphabet, there are missing characters on the PDF invoice. I expect it's something to do with UTF-8.
Is there a way to show these missing Cyrillic / Russian characters?

Comment: sorry, I meant Cyrillic alphabet. I also need to know about Arabic and Chinese characters too.

Comment: Maybe its just the font used in the PDF not supporting that characters?

Comment: I'm using Arial. Does that support Cyrillic characters?

Comment: according to ms that should work. so my clue was wrong :-/ http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1705

Comment: I **think** I need change the output from UTF-8 to ISOxxxx-5 (whichever one does cyrillic characters). Not sure how though!

Answer (score 1):

A solution I implemented is the string transliteration.

We ported the nice [transliteration extension from Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) and made it work on Magento for PDF printing and logistics data exchange.

To transliterate strings means that characters are converted to US-ASCII.

That's a solution that may or may not suit your needs, because the data becomes different from the original.

Answer (score 0):

If possible store and translate the contents of the email on the fly as you populate the pdf.  This way you'll ensure a full translation is present in the file.

Comment: There isn't an email. The customer orders something from our website, and the details are correctly transferring into Magento. But when I go to print out the invoice, the cyrillic characters don't show.

Comment: are you getting a bunch of [][][][] or do the characters actually disappear?

Comment: They just disappear. The address should be:

Нагорный проезд, д.6
Moscow, Москва, 117105
Russia

And it appears like this:
 , .6 Moscow,
, 117105
Russia

Comment: If the method you're using doesn't work with chinese or arabic it probably has trouble recognizing moonrunes.  If this is the case, and you've tried different fonts i'd suggest a full scrap of your current methods.