# Problem with diacritical marks

Tags: invoice, pdf, ce-1.9.2.0, delivery

My website sells a lot of products to people in Europe, and as is to be expected, some of the customer names feature diacritical marks. Unfortunately, the names with diacritical marks don't show on the delivery and invoice. It just removes the whole name, even the parts that don't feature diacritical marks.

Here's some example of names with diacritical marks:
Artūras Nalivaika,
Jurgita Dapkevičiūtė

What can I do?

Comment: if you are change customer name form admin side in customer mange section then no effect in sales section. bcz sales order, invoice & shipment section customer name is save in different database table. for eg. sales_flat_order

Comment: Thanks - but I don't want to change the customer name. I just want to be able to print the invoices with all the others.

Comment: need to updates name for  all orders or particulate customer name "diacritical marks" orders?

Comment: Are there entries in the logs? Is a third-party extension involved? In which way does this relate to your earlier question http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/42100/22855 ?

Comment: Where should I look in the logs? I'm not using any third-party extensions for PDF invoices/delivery notes. And yes, it's similar to the previous question (which I didn't get an definitive solution to), but I've noticed that non-cyrillic characters such as ū are affected as well.